# Unable to connect the Bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I will be brief and concise as I believe there is a quick fix for my current issue. I am using bootstrap using a blank template and I cannot get my stylesheet to connect for some reason? All the files live within the same directory. My patience is wearing thin due to the unnecessary set backs. If you have any answers or suggestions they would be much appreciataed:). I've posted the HTML below, thanks!

Justin

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Justin A Henderson</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <!---jumbotron--->
   <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Justin Henderson</h1>
    </div>
   </div>


    <!--nav-->
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you used your browser's built-in developer tools to find out the fully qualified URI `../css/bootstrap.css` is being resolved into? By seeing what your browser is *trying* to do, might give you everything you need to fix it.

Comment: You say "***All** the files live within the **same** directory*", yet you reference your stylesheet as follows `../css/bootstrap.css`. So they are **not** all in the same directory? Be more consise please.

Comment: If they were in the same directory your bootstrap.css reference should be `<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Also, you reference your Bootstrap JS as `js/bootstrap.min.js`. If I had to guess, I'd try `href="css/bootstrap.css"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your HTML file is called `justin.html`, and it lives in a folder called `site`:

```
site
|
+-- justin.html
```

Your bootstrap CSS file is shown as `..\css\bootstrap.css`, which says: go up one level, into the CSS folder, and get `bootstrap.css`, which would mean you'd need the following directory structure for it to work:

```
<parent folder>
|
+-- css
|   |
+   +-- bootstrap.css
|
+-- site
    |
    +-- justin.html
```

But I bet your `css` folder is actually *inside* `site`, along with your `js` folder, for example:

```
site
|
+-- css
|   |
|   +-- bootstrap.css
|
+-- js
|   |
|   +-- bootstrap.min.js
|
+-- justin.html
```

The correct path would then be:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: so here is an example of the current file path:

justinhenderson>bootstrap>css>bootstrap.css

According to the example file path above my current HTML link tag is as follows: 

'<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">'

This is still producing the same result. Is there something I'm still overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be linking back too far judging by your JS link, try:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```